# Controlling time with async await in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await, combine

Up to now I've been using `Combine` and the PointFree TestSchedulers https://github.com/pointfreeco/combine-schedulers to "control time" in my tests.

I can make a request and then assert values at certain points in the process without any trouble.

Example...

```
func testFetchContentSuccess() {
    let queue = TestSchedulerOf<DispatchQueue>(now: .init(.now()))

    let sut = sut(queue: queue.eraseToAnyScheduler())

    XCTAssertEqual(sut.content, .notAsked)

    sut.fetchContent()

    XCTAssertEqual(sut.content, .loading) // this would be impossible without a TestScheulder as the mock endpoint would return immediately.

    queue.advance() // this is what I'm looking for from async await

    assertSnapshot(matching: sut.content, as: .dump)
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar with async await?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's awesome!

You can just declare test methods as `async`, then `await` right in the test method.

So if this test is really about the results of the fetch, it could just be:

```
func testFetchContentSuccess() {
    let sut = ContentFetcher()

    XCTAssertEqual(sut.content, .notAsked)

    await sut.fetchContent()

    assertSnapshot(matching: sut.content, as: .dump)
}
```

I have lots of tests that use `XCTestExpectation`, and most get a lot shorter and easier to read when they're converted to be async/await based.

Comment: Would I be able to intercept before the `fetchContent` has actually finished?